# Excel - find the average of the top 3 prices for each product type

Tags: excel

I have a list of clothes (shirts, jumpers, pants and jackets) in different colors and sizes in the first column. The second column lists the prices for each of them.
How do I write a formula to find the average of the top 3 prices for each type of clothing?
I tried to do this using array formulas, but when I tried to use asterisks for the wildcard, nothing worked.

```
Brown jacket size M $50         Avg top-3 price
Black shirt size L  $22     shirt   $42
Blue pants size L   $40     jumper  $44
Grey jumper size L  $49     pants   $40
White jumper size M $47     jacket  $39
Brown pants size L  $44         
White shirt size M  $38         
Black jacket size S $27         
White jacket size L $41         
Brown jumper size L $36         
Blue jumper size S  $23         
Brown shirt size S  $45         
Black pants size S  $37         
Grey pants size M   $31         
Black jumper size M $30         
Blue jacket size M  $28         
Grey jacket size S  $21         
Grey shirt size S   $36         
Blue shirt size M   $44         
White pants size S  $36
```

[screenshot of Excel spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/buXwZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use
=SUMIF(A2:A22,"**shirt* *",B2:B22)/COUNTIF(A2:A22,"*shirt *")

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, your formula calculates the average price for all occurrences of the word "shirt" (185/5 = 37).
I need to find the three largest values (45, 44, 38) for the word "shirt" and calculate their arithmetic mean (result = 42).

Comment: Ah ok, maybe you can add a column to rank the amounts? then change my previous formula to =SUMIFS(B2:B22,A2:A22,"*shirt *",C2:C22,<=3)/3

See for rank:
https://exceljet.net/formula/rank-if-formula

Comment: I understood your idea, but I cannot understand it in the formula. I need to rank by price based on multiple values in cells E2: E5. I figured out how to rank by one cell E2. `=COUNTIFS(A:A,"*"&$E$2&"*",B:B,">"&B2)+1` But how to write in the formula so that the ranking of the required row occurs according to one of the possible parameters from the list E2: E5? https://prnt.sc/1t8so36

Comment: Something like this? https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4319-excel-rank-by-group.html

Answer (score 0):

So the solution is (For example for **Shirt**):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(LARGE(($C$2:$C$21=E2)*($B$2:$B$21),{1,2,3}))/$F$1
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately, I do not have a separate column (C:C) indicating the type of product in the source data. I need a formula that works with partial occurrence of a word in column (A:A).

Comment: I tried changing the formula like this: 
`=SUMPRODUCT(LARGE(($A$2:$A$21="*"&E2&"*")*($B$2:$B$21),{1,2,3}))/$F$1`

but unfortunately the excel cannot handle
`"*"&E2&"*"`

Comment: Why don't you seperate coloumn? Add new column and "Flash Fill" feature will automatically add the type of products. Don't think that you will write product types one by one.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1KimYFzET1w

Comment: The idea is good, it's just that the task I set is greatly simplified. This can be the average for the type, color or size of the product. There are only three product parameters listed here, in fact there can be many more in any of the cells in column A. And autofill for each subcategory simply does not work. Therefore, the formula should work with a mask of asterisks.

Comment: Excel does not like wildcards/asteriks. That's why you should use different columns for different data. At C Column; =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("jac";A2));"Jacket";"")